ASP.NET Core Web API - Blazor WASM - CORS error after some time
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and Blazor Wasm on .NET 8, JWT
In the API the program looks like this.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>{policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials();});
});

...

var app = builder.Build();

...

app.UseCors();

I deployed and everything works fine. After almost a week I started receiving this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://backend.net/api/packages/fullpackage' from origin 'https://frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

When I look at the preflight, I get this.

access-control-allow-credentials: true access-control-allow-headers:
authorization,content-type access-control-allow-methods: POST

And the request gets this.

URL: https://backend.net/api/packages/fullpackage Method: POST Code:
500 Internal Server Error Directive: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

It happens once, but I really need that online, after looking everywhere I tried switching from the API host and it worked again. That was like a week ago, now I have the same problem.
I already tried these things:

Changing CORS specifying the frontend URL
Restarting the application pool
Cleaning the application pool
Clearing cache
Adding a custom policy and enabling in the controller with [EnableCors(PolicyName="name"]
Disable CORS in the controller with [DisableCors]

I've seen a lot of QA here and different ways to do it.
Is there something I'm missing?
Also the first time that worked used this:
app.UseCors(x => x
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
       .AllowCredentials());

Then I switched to the builder like I said at the beginning, but didn't work until I switched host and url.
Thank you in advance
Edit, this is the full code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.


builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TSystem API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. <br /> <br />
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.<br /> <br />
                      Example: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'<br /> <br />",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
      {
        {
          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
          {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
              {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
              },
              Scheme = "oauth2",
              Name = "Bearer",
              In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            },
            new List<string>()
          }
        });
});

Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("MYLIC");

var isDev = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment;

if (isDev.Invoke())
{
    //LocalConnection
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer("name=LocalConnection"));
}
else
{
    //CloudConnection
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer("name=CloudConnection"));
}


builder.Services.AddTransient<SeedDb>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiService, ApiService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileStorage, FileStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMailHelper, MailHelper>();


builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(x =>
{
    x.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider;
    x.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    x.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    x.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    x.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    x.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    x.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    x.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x => x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["jwtKey"]!)),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    });


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => { policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials(); });
});

//This tried calling it from the controller
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "DefaultCorsPolicy", policy => { policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials(); });
});


var app = builder.Build();
SeedData(app);

void SeedData(WebApplication app)
{
    IServiceScopeFactory? scopedFactory = app.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

    using (IServiceScope? scope = scopedFactory!.CreateScope())
    {
        SeedDb? service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SeedDb>();
        service!.SeedAsync().Wait();
    }
}



app.UseCors();


//app.UseCors(x => x
//.AllowAnyMethod()
//.AllowAnyHeader()
//.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
//.AllowCredentials());


//app.UseCors(x => x
//       .AllowAnyMethod()
//       .AllowAnyHeader()
//       .WithOrigins("https://frontend.com")  //changed the original name
//       .AllowCredentials());





// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


what does it mean for  I tried switching from the API host and it worked again.? It looks like this workaround could help solve the issue temporarily.

I'm using Interserver hosting, got a new account and hosted the Api there and worked like a week. But I need something permanent. I'm about to buy in other host to check if that's the problem. But I have other thing hosted there and this is the first time with this kind of weird error.

I suspect you're not stacking your middleware in the correct order. In particular, the CORS middleware should occur before any auth middleware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order

daandsp Told me about it and switched some things. But the same result.

Looks like the server is only allowing POST methods. Is this a POST?

Normally, codes shall always work or always not work. It's weird that switching from the API could solve the issue for one week. But about CORS error, if we have delegate or proxy before the server and it might occur as well. So that I'm afraid it's related to the server too, I agree with you to test in other host or server.

I switched host and now it works. But I don´t know if it will happen again. But I think I figured out. The error is when the browser do the preflight  looking for available methods. The method that isn't working or stop working is the Options method.  I explicit declared the methods instead of AllowAnyMethod and started working in the previous host. Still weird situation.

Yes, a common error for preflight request get CORS error back is that the application integrate windows auth which doesn't allow anonymous option request so that the preflight request can't get the CORS policy back and get the CORS error. And another common scenario is that the server has a load balancor in front on itself but the load balancor doesn't set CORS policy, but both of them are not your case.

May I know whether the issue appeared again or not after switching the host? If yes, may I know whether you test in another sever and does the issue still occur? I searched about the symptom recently, but no luck. What I could find is that we need to set CORS policy for cross-region scenario.

Thank you. Still working Ok and I hope it continues that way. I'll catch you up if I find anything else. I think that not getting the options back was the problem.

There's no update in the last 2 weeks, does it mean everything is always working well these days?

I can't post the answer, but this is the final answer and what it works: Adding [HttpOptions] method to the controller.
The WebDAVModule set PUT and DELETE request methods disabled by default and due to that PUT and DELETE throw 405 errors.
To make the PUT and DELETE requests work, we need to override the WebDAVModule setting in web.config file by adding the below settings under the system.webServer.
<system.webServer>  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">   <remove name="WebDAVModule" />  </modules> </system.webServer>

Link where I found the info:
[link]https://dev.to/techiesdiary/error-405-aspnet-core-web-api-put-and-delete-methods-not-allowed-222j

You should set the allowed origins of a request in the AddCors() call.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .WithOrigins("https://frontend.com")
        .AllowCredentials()
    );
});

Be sure to call the AddCors() before configuring anything like controllers or mvc.
Then call the UseCors() method.
app.UseCors();

You can read more on enabling Cross-Origin requests in ASP.NET Core in the documentation.
Hope this helps

I just copied and pasted your answer, changing the Url, cleared caché and the same error.

In that case, can you share a bit more of your program.cs? In what order are you adding services? Also, did you read through the documentation?

Updated my answer with a bit more detail

I edited with the full program.cs

You need to call AddCors() before calling the AddControllers() method.

I just did.  Same result. `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => { policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowCredentials(); });
});
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);`

You're using SetIsOriginAllowed() instead of WithOrigins()

I did before, but I tried now. And the same result, I even added some extra domain configuration. The SetIsOriginAllowed I was using it to allow anyorigin builder.Services.AddCors(options => {     options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => { policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("https://frontend.com","https://www.frontend.com","frontend.com").AllowCredentials(); }); });
